# JavaScript Array reserves undefined elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

In google chrome console, if I initialize an array:

```
var arr = [];
arr[5] = 10;
```

then printing `arr` in console says:

```
[undefined × 5, 10]
```

1. `undefined x 5` is it only chrome's representation or actual memory
   reserved?
2. What's the difference between `arr[4]` and `arr[6]` as
   both prints `undefined`?
3. What's the use of reserved `undefined x 5`, if it's actually reserved space?

Comment: In FF output is little cleaner: Array [ <5 empty slots>, 10 ], so  it is different browser representation for the same thing...

Comment: console.log is browser dependant

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/question/3403097/javascript-array-index-problem)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. undefined x 5 is it only chrome's representation or actual memory reserved?

No.

What you are describing is called a *sparse* array. In Javascript, the arrays are inherently *sparse*. The existence of `arr[5]` does not imply the existence of `arr[0]`. Memory is not allocated up to the max index.

You could see an array in Javascript as a type of Object. The keys are the indices. In fact, you could even do this:

```
arr[3.14] = 'pi';
```

`3.14` is the key, and `pi` is the value. A key/value pair. It is similar to declaring this object:

```
var arr = { '3.14': 'pi' }
```

The properties that do not exist, well do not exist.

Arrays differ in the way that they are *arrays*, meaning they have indices and are zero-based. Hence, for indices (read keys) `0` thru to `n`, the values are `undefined`.

If you do a `arr[200000] = 'something'`, it does not mean that `0` thru `19999` will be sitting there wasting memory.

> 2. What's the difference between arr[4] and arr[6] as both prints undefined?

No difference. Well, "undefined" means *undefined*. In Javascript you can very well refer to indices well beyond the max declared, and there is no *out-of-bound* thingy. You only get *"undefined"*.

> 3. What's the use of reserved undefined x 5, if it's actually reserved space?

It could be both be a convenience and inconvenient. Just depends on how you see it. Regarding reserved space, no. See point 1 above.

You can easily verify this by iterating the array. See the small example below, and you will understand that `0` thru to `4` do not exist.

Example:

```js
// Only for snippet demo
console.log = function(txt) {  var result = document.getElementById("result"); result.innerHTML += txt + "<br/>"; }
                             
// demo to iterate sparse array
var arr = [];
arr[5] = 10;

arr.forEach(function(elem, idx) {
    console.log(idx + " = " + elem);
});
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

---

There are typed arrays as well. These are not sparse arrays, and hence you cannot introduce gaps with typed arrays. For example:

```
var int16 = new Int16Array(2);
```

Comment: This is very technical subject (for amateurs like me), but could i ask why: http://jsfiddle.net/gcbra0ue/ array length is 6?

Comment: @nevermind: That is because it is an *array*. Arrays are different form objects in the way that they have indices and are zero-based. Hence, the length of an array would be the highest index + 1. However, the *gaps* are well, undefined.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so memory is not allocated (spaces aren't reserved), there are no 5 variables with default value - undefined, in memory. If i do something like this: var first=arr[0]; then memory space should be reserved (with default value:undefined), if i understand correctly?

Comment: Yes @nevermind, now you are explicitly declaring a variable.

Comment: For `arr.forEach` or `key in arr` we can only say `undefined` slots are not Enumerable for Array (if I am right). As for `arr[4.5] = 10` '4.5' is not Enumerable. Why FF labels them as _slots_ at all?

Comment: @abdul-wahab: (1) `arr[4.5]` is not enumerable because it is now an Object. However, you can still iterate using the `for..in` syntax. But, this is now no longer an array. Why? Because arrays are those objects which have a nonnegative integer less than 2^32. (2) As per the [official specs of ECMAScript5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18), `forEach` invokes callback *only for elements of the array which actually exist*. (3) In any case, remember that JavaScript arrays anyway do not require an up front allocation of memory unlike typed arrays.

Comment: All this confusion arises because of these browser consoles. Somehow the implementations (FF, Chrome etc.) decided to show an array like that in the console. Just a representational notion.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a value to the x. index of an array that is currently empty,
the array length will be updated.

See: [Array at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), there it says:

> When setting a property on a JavaScript array when the property is a valid array index and that index is outside the current bounds of the array, the engine will update the array's length property accordingly

Comment: If I assign `arr[999] = 10` `arr.length` says 1000. Does it mean, `arr` reserves 999 `undefined` elements?

Comment: The 'undefined' that comes infront of the message is not relevant to the data in the array. But yes, if you do a console.log for array[0] when data is not provided will result in undefined.

Comment: There is no memory reserved as in C arrays, because a JavaScript array is just a list and holds references ("pointers") to its elements.

Comment: However, typed arrays are different beasts. They don't allow gap/holes as in untyped sparse ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Length of array will be 6 in this case as you are allocating 6th position in the array. Rest all the indexes will carry `null` value..

Example below will give you better idea:

```js
var arr = [];
arr[5] = 10;
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<div id='element'></div>
```

Comment: But `undefined` and `null` are different primitives. `undefined === null` results in false and `typeof null` results in "object".

Comment: In this case, JSON can not store undefined, it will store null. The real vale of `arr[4]` and `arr[6]` is undefined as you have not defined it anywhere. In any browser this behaviour will not change..

Comment: `JSON.stringify` has nothing to do with sparse arrays. It doesn't know beforehand whether the array you are serialising is having holes or not. It simply iterates using the `length` and reports `null` for non-existent properties. The fact is, there are non-existent elements in an array and that's all there is to it.

Comment: @Abhitalks, Purpose of using `JSON.stringify` was to demonstrate length and values present in array nothing more than that..If we define length or an array without really adding values, then the value remains `undefined` and this is what I want to espress..

Answer (score -1):

it means the sixth entry is `10`,

all the other are empty (`undefined` ).

```js
var arr = [];
arr[5] = 10;
console.log(arr[4])
```